# How to fix PowerShell 7 fonts not showing correctly | oh-my-posh

Tags: powershell, terminal

I've already installed Windows Terminal, set it up with "oh my posh" and everything working as intended.
Though whenever I launch PowerShell 7 (without the terminal), the font is messy as you can see at the image below

[image]

**I have already tried to change the font, to the same one I used in terminal's .json but there are still some parts that are not rendering correctly and I cannot use it that way with VSCode**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because the Windows Console [doesn't fully support UTF-8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/#console-built-in-a-pre-unicode-dawn):

> Windows Console was created way back in the early days of Windows,
> back before Unicode itself existed! Back then, a decision was made to
> represent each text character as a fixed-length 16-bit value (UCS-2).
> Thus, the Console’s text buffer contains 2-byte wchar_t values per
> grid cell, x columns by y rows in size.
> ...
> One problem, for example, is that because UCS-2 is a fixed-width
> 16-bit encoding, it is [unable to represent all Unicode codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#/media/File:Unifont_Full_Map.png).

This means you have "partial" support for Unicode characters in the Windows Console (i.e. as long as the character can be represented in UCS-2), but won't support all potential (32-bit) Unicode regions.

When you see boxes, that means that the character that is being used is using a region outside of the UCS-2 range. You also tell this because you get 2 boxes (i.e. 2 x 16 bit values). That is why you can't have happy faces  in your Windows Console (which makes me sad ☹️).

In order for it to work in all locations, you will have to modify your oh-my-posh themes to use a different character that can be represented with a UCS-2 character.

For [Version 2](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/upgrading#enter-v3) of Oh My Posh, to make the font changes you have to edit the `$ThemeSettings` variable. Follow the instructions on the GitHub on [configuring Theme Settings](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh#configuration). e.g.:

```
$ThemeSettings.GitSymbols.BranchSymbol = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x2514)
```

For Version 3+ of Oh My Posh, you have to edit the JSON [configuration](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/configure) file to make the changes, e.g.:

```
...
{
    "type": "git",
    "style": "powerline",
    "powerline_symbol": "\u2514",
....
```